# Jquery: Problems with dynamically added rows

Tags: jquery, event-handling, datatable

Folks,

I am using jquery datatable plugin, in this an advanced grid automatically gets created with rows in table. Now I am getting problem when I dynamically add rows to this table. Actually, I am having image in one of  of this table, on click of which I open a popup. Here what my problem begins, In my application, user edits values of table row and to reflect them in actual table I have user html() function of jquery. In this I have again created image in  which was previously there. but the popup action gets removed(which I have added on onclick event). Please help me with this??

Thanks in advance,
Rahul

Answer (score 1):

Change the onclick handler for your image to use [Live Events](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

I can give you a more specific answer if you post the jQuery code that you are using for adding the rows.